# Eclipse Plugins: Cannot start an unneeded plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I've written a simple Eclipse plugin to import preferences from the command line, which appears to work quite well. The plugin executes using `eclipsec.exe -consoleLog -console -noSplash -application headless.prefs.import preferences.epf` but after the plugin executes, and eclipse calls the `stop()` method in my Activator, the execution of another Plugin breaks:

Stack trace: (The top two lines are my plugin exiting)

---

```
Preferences Imported.
Importer exit.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2015-07-07 14:06:49.300
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BundleContext is no longer valid
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.checkValid(BundleContextImpl.java:931)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.createFilter(BundleContextImpl.java:917)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.<init>(ServiceTracker.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDERegistryStrategy.getXMLParser(PDERegistryStrategy.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.addContribution(ExtensionRegistry.java:1062)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDERegistryStrategy.addBundle(PDERegistryStrategy.java:209)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDERegistryStrategy.addBundles(PDERegistryStrategy.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDERegistryStrategy.processBundles(PDERegistryStrategy.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDERegistryStrategy.onStart(PDERegistryStrategy.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.<init>(ExtensionRegistry.java:725)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.RegistryFactory.createRegistry(RegistryFactory.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDEExtensionRegistry.createRegistry(PDEExtensionRegistry.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDEExtensionRegistry.getRegistry(PDEExtensionRegistry.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDEExtensionRegistry.getExtensionPoint(PDEExtensionRegistry.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDEExtensionRegistry.findExtensions(PDEExtensionRegistry.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.SourceLocationManager.processExtensions(SourceLocationManager.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.SourceLocationManager.getExtensionLocations(SourceLocationManager.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.SourceLocationManager.searchExtensionLocations(SourceLocationManager.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.SourceLocationManager.findSourcePath(SourceLocationManager.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.ClasspathUtilCore.getSourceAnnotation(ClasspathUtilCore.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDEClasspathContainer.addExternalPlugin(PDEClasspathContainer.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.addPlugin(RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.j
ava:256)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.addDependency(RequiredPluginsClasspathContain
er.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.addDependency(RequiredPluginsClasspathContain
er.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.computePluginEntries(RequiredPluginsClasspath
Container.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.RequiredPluginsClasspathContainer.getClasspathEntries(RequiredPluginsClasspathC
ontainer.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.containerPutIfInitializingWithSameEntries(JavaModelManager.jav
a:645)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SetContainerOperation.executeOperation(SetContainerOperation.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:788)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1879)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2811)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2689)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2853)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1958)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ExternalFoldersManager.refreshReferences(ExternalFoldersManager.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessor.java:2004)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessingState.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessingState.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.handleEvent(NotificationManager.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastEvent(Workspace.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1662)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.RefreshJob.runInWorkspace(RefreshJob.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

---

It should be noted that the plugin is working, and earlier I was getting "Cannot transient Start the bundle  .. .. The bundle's start level is not met".

*Is there a way of configuring my plugin.xml or activator to try and clear these errors, or to force exit eclipse from the `stop()` method?* nothing else needs to be called after that.

Comment: Do you mean you are calling the 'stop' method? Only Eclipse should be calling the Activator stop method.

Comment: No, I am not calling the stop method, I meant that after eclipse has called the stop method, eclipse will crash